# NSString en/decode base64

Tags: php, objective-c, base64, encryption

I am trying to make a equilvant of these php functions to encrype/decrypt in objective c￼ but with no luck so far.

I counld't find any base64_en/decode methods in obj-c, is there any?

```
function encrypt($string, $key) {

    ￼$result = '';

￼    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {

        ￼$char = substr($string, $i, 1);
        ￼$keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
        ￼$char = chr(ord($char) + ord($keychar));
        ￼$result .= $char;
￼    }
￼
    return base64_encode($result);
￼}


￼function decrypt($string, $key) {

    ￼$result = '';
    ￼$string = base64_decode($string);

    ￼for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {

        ￼$char = substr($string, $i, 1);
        ￼$keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
        ￼$char = chr(ord($char) - ord($keychar));
        ￼$result.=$char;
    ￼}

    ￼return $result;
￼}
```

Ty already!

Comment: Minor point:  Converting to/from Base64 is not encrypting/decrypting.

Comment: If you Google "IOS BASE64" you'll find several 3rd party Base64 conversion packages, such as https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this category I use for this very task, it's an `NSString` category for converting strings to md5, base64 etc...

https://gist.github.com/3907443

From `NSString` to `NSData`:

```
+ (NSString *)encodeBase64WithString:(NSString *)strData {
    return [NSString encodeBase64WithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Encode from `NSData`:

```
+ (NSString *)encodeBase64WithData:(NSData *)objData {
    const unsigned char * objRawData = [objData bytes];
    char * objPointer;
    char * strResult;

    // Get the Raw Data length and ensure we actually have data
    int intLength = [objData length];
    if (intLength == 0) return nil;

    // Setup the String-based Result placeholder and pointer within that placeholder
    strResult = (char *)calloc(((intLength + 2) / 3) * 4, sizeof(char));
    objPointer = strResult;

    // Iterate through everything
    while (intLength > 2) { // keep going until we have less than 24 bits
        *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[objRawData[0] >> 2];
        *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[((objRawData[0] & 0x03) << 4) + (objRawData[1] >> 4)];
        *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[((objRawData[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + (objRawData[2] >> 6)];
        *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[objRawData[2] & 0x3f];

        // we just handled 3 octets (24 bits) of data
        objRawData += 3;
        intLength -= 3; 
    }

    // now deal with the tail end of things
    if (intLength != 0) {
        *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[objRawData[0] >> 2];
        if (intLength > 1) {
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[((objRawData[0] & 0x03) << 4) + (objRawData[1] >> 4)];
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[(objRawData[1] & 0x0f) << 2];
            *objPointer++ = '=';
        } else {
            *objPointer++ = _base64EncodingTable[(objRawData[0] & 0x03) << 4];
            *objPointer++ = '=';
            *objPointer++ = '=';
        }
    }

    // Terminate the string-based result
    *objPointer = '\0';

    // Return the results as an NSString object
    return [NSString stringWithCString:strResult encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Decode:

```
+ (NSData *)decodeBase64WithString:(NSString *)strBase64 {
    const char * objPointer = [strBase64 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    int intLength = strlen(objPointer);
    int intCurrent;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k;

    unsigned char * objResult;
    objResult = calloc(intLength, sizeof(char));

    // Run through the whole string, converting as we go
    while ( ((intCurrent = *objPointer++) != '\0') && (intLength-- > 0) ) {
        if (intCurrent == '=') {
            if (*objPointer != '=' && ((i % 4) == 1)) {// || (intLength > 0)) {
                // the padding character is invalid at this point -- so this entire string is invalid
                free(objResult);
                return nil;
            }
            continue;
        }

        intCurrent = _base64DecodingTable[intCurrent];
        if (intCurrent == -1) {
            // we're at a whitespace -- simply skip over
            continue;
        } else if (intCurrent == -2) {
            // we're at an invalid character
            free(objResult);
            return nil;
        }

        switch (i % 4) {
            case 0:
                objResult[j] = intCurrent << 2;
                break;

            case 1:
                objResult[j++] |= intCurrent >> 4;
                objResult[j] = (intCurrent & 0x0f) << 4;
                break;

            case 2:
                objResult[j++] |= intCurrent >>2;
                objResult[j] = (intCurrent & 0x03) << 6;
                break;

            case 3:
                objResult[j++] |= intCurrent;
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // mop things up if we ended on a boundary
    k = j;
    if (intCurrent == '=') {
        switch (i % 4) {
            case 1:
                // Invalid state
                free(objResult);
                return nil;

            case 2:
                k++;
                // flow through
            case 3:
                objResult[k] = 0;
        }
    }

    // Cleanup and setup the return NSData
    NSData * objData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:objResult length:j] autorelease];
    free(objResult);
    return objData;
}
```

Comment: I'm using the same code, or very similar and it doesn't support special characters. Part of it is that his encryption method adds the value of 2 character's ASCII code. Using an `NSASCIIStringEncoding` only gives you access to the first 128 characters of the ASCII table, therefore those base64 methods won't work. It would work for regular text though. Part of it is because, in your encode method, you're converting an your NSData into a `const unsigned char *` to a `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. That way, you're losing the top 128 characters, which would cause character loss.